# Java: Crear bucle para almacenar en ArrayList

Tags: java, bucle-for, arraylist

tengo un problema con crear un bucle de distintas preguntas y almacenarlo en un ArrayList, el ejercicio consiste en dar 5 becas a distintos alumnos mediante unas condiciones, y almacenar en un ArrayList solo aquellos alumnos que han conseguido la beca. De momento mediante el código solo he conseguido almacenar un alumno, pero necesito que las preguntas se repitan hasta que haya 5 becados.
Estoy empezando y el ejercicio me parece interesante. Gracias de antemano por la respuesta.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main (String [] args){
    
    int edad;
    String nom;
    boolean titulo, atur, beca;
    
    ArrayList <String> becados = new ArrayList();
    Scanner becas = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Como te llamas?");
    nom = becas.next();
    
    System.out.println("Que edad tienes?");
    edad = becas.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println("Tienes algun titulo universitario? (responder con si o no)");
    String uni = becas.next();
    
    titulo = (uni.toLowerCase().equals("Si")) ? true : false;
    
    System.out.println("Estas en el paro?");
    String paro = becas.next();
    
    atur = (paro.toLowerCase().equals("Si")) ? true : false;

    
    if((edad >= 18 && titulo == true) || atur == true){
        beca = true;
        becados.add(nom);
        System.out.println("Tienes una beca");
        System.out.println("Estas es la lista de becados: " + becados);
    }else {
        beca = false;
        System.out.println("No puedes participar");
        System.out.println("No estas en la lista de becados");
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tienes algún error en el código que he intentado corregir

Además, he agregado una clase para el objeto Alumno donde poder almacenar los datos de cada alumno que metemos por teclado y sea becado

Te paso la clase alumnos:

```
class Alumnos {
    //declaramos las variables string
    private String nombre;
    private String sEdad;
    private String uni;
    private String paro;

    //instanciamos el contructor de la clase que recibe los datos de cada alumno por parámetro
    public void alumnos(String nombre, String sEdad, String uni, String paro){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.sEdad = sEdad;
        this.uni = uni;
        this.paro = paro;
    }

    //métodos get
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public String getEdad() {
        return sEdad;
    }
    public String getUni() {
        return uni;
    }
    public String getParo() {
        return paro;
    }

    //métodos set   
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public void setEdad(String edad) {
        this.sEdad = edad;
    }
    public void setUni(String uni) {
        this.uni = uni;
    }
    public void setParo(String paro) {
        this.paro = paro;
    }

}
```

Y ahora el método main, en él verás algún método diferente al tuyo al haber corregido algún error que tenías y agregada alguna funcionalidad más:

```
public static void main (String [] args){


    int edad;
    String nom;
    int AlumBecados = 0;
    boolean titulo, atur, beca;
    //en tu arrayList, sustituimos String por la clase Alumnos
    ArrayList <Alumnos> becados = new ArrayList();
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    //El bucle que pide los 5 becados    
    while(AlumBecados < 5){

        //creamos el objeto alumno
        Alumnos alumno = new Alumnos();

        //pedimos los datos            
        System.out.println("Como te llamas?");
        nom = teclado.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Que edad tienes?");
        edad = teclado.nextInt();
        //limpiamos el bufer del teclado, ésto lo hacemos siempre después de meter un número
        teclado.nextLine();
        //guardamos el número como string
        String sEdad = String.valueOf(edad);            

        System.out.println("Tienes algun titulo universitario? (responder con si o no)");
        String uni = teclado.nextLine();

        //convertimos titulo en boolean sin distinción de mayúsculas   
        titulo = (uni.equalsIgnoreCase("Si")) ? true : false;

        System.out.println("Estas en el paro?");
        String paro = teclado.nextLine();

        //convertimos atur en boolean sin distinción de mayúsuculas
        atur = (paro.equalsIgnoreCase("Si")) ? true : false;

        //hacemos tu evaluación
        if((edad >= 18 && titulo == true) || atur == true){
            beca = true;
            //agregamos los datos al objeto alumno
            alumno.setNombre(nom);
            alumno.setEdad(sEdad);
            alumno.setUni(uni);
            alumno.setParo(paro);
            //agregamos el objeto alumno al arrayList becados
            becados.add(alumno);
            //aumentamos en uno el número de becados
            AlumBecados ++;
            //damos información del alumno becado
            System.out.println(nom + ", has obtenido una beca, Contigo hay " + AlumBecados + " becados");
        }else {
            beca = false;
            System.out.println("Lo siento, no estas en la lista de becados");
        }
    }
    
    //mostramos los datos de los alumnos becados
    for(int i = 0; i < becados.size(); i++) {
         System.out.println("===============================================");
        System.out.println(becados.get(i).getNombre());
        System.out.println(becados.get(i).getEdad());
        System.out.println(becados.get(i).getUni());
        System.out.println(becados.get(i).getParo());
        System.out.println("===============================================");
    }
}
```

Comment: Muy correcta, pero ya que haces modificaciones, modifica esto: `(uni.equalsIgnoreCase("Si")) ? true : false` -> No tiene absolutamente ningún sentido usar un ternario para devolver "true" o "false" cuando el propio método te va a devolver exactamente eso... ese ternario significa literalmente "if true return true".... --> `titulo = uni.equalsIgnoreCase("Si");` mucho más breve y fácil de leer, y funciona exactamente igual

Comment: Hola @Benito-B, intenté dejar la mayor parte de su código e intentar que se diera cuenta de donde tenía los errores, de ahí que en esa parte que indicas, me limitase a sustituir su instrucción, que no funcionaba de forma correcta, por la mía, aunque evidentemente, de la misma contestación a la pregunta, se obtiene el mismo resultado y esas líneas sobrarían. Un saludo

Comment: Buenas tardes, muchas gracias a los dos por vuestra respuesta, ya he podido entender varias cosas buenas y malas que he hecho en mi código. Gracias de nuevo y saludos.